# how to get a reference of an android view from a react-native component?

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to get the android view that represent/shows/display a react-native component, i understand one component may have more than one view, having the father of all the views is perfect, or having a child is also good...

I am not able to find info how to map react-native component to native view.
I am willing to read code, websites anything, please just point me in the right direction.
Thanks a lot!

I tried reading code, and also using the layout inspector to try to find something that points from one to the other.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: <React-Native-Component> on run time is translated to a view, or a group of views, how do I get the reference on the android side or on the react-native side.